# WebKit JavaScript object property iteration degrades horribly when mixing integers and long strings

Tags: javascript, performance, properties, webkit

I'm iterating over the properties of a large object in JavaScript and have come up against a bottleneck specifically in [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) browsers I can't seem to code round.

Basically if I have an object which is mainly keyed by integer values as properties (1, 2, 4, 10678, etc.) and then add in a few long property names ("somelongdescriptorofaproperty") the performance when iterating over the object degrades by 10 times or more (and in my worst case by 80x!)

This doesn't happen if I have an object whose properties are a lot of short strings and a few long strings, so it's not a case of "integers are just faster dude". Mixing the two seems to be the factor.

Have a look at this ill-named jsperf to see my point -->
http://jsperf.com/object-recursion

Why is this happening? Is this a WebKit 'feature' and what is a way round this? To have separate objects containing just the integer properties and the long-winded properties?

Comment: I don't know if this is an option, but when the iteration is faster when there are short strings instead of integers, I would prepend and underscore or an a or something to the number, so that you have property names like _0, _1, _2 or a0, a1, a2 and so on.

Comment: It's a thought but it would make things awkward when trying to access the properties again using these integers that another part of my program supplies. It's certainly a fallback I hadn't considered if I can't split the object into two for each type of property descriptor. Thanks for replying!